# Right angle adapter for LED strip?

Tags: lighting, led

I have a cabinet that I'm adding LED strips to, and I'd like to cover each side of the interior without bending the strip at angle changes. Do 90 degree adapters exist that would make this transition from one side to another possible without bending the strip? Like this (red area would be the LED strip):

[image]

Comment: **LED strip inside corner connectors** in your search endine of choice if you are looking for the "red path" type of corner. Delete "inside" for other options (well, search engines will cough up irrelevant results anyway, but you can get more of them that way.) Bending it between LEDs should be a non-issue in that direction, though.

Comment: It's much better to bend than have extra connections, which will make each downstream section a bit dimmer than the previous. I've even bent right angles width-wise using two severe 45 deg angles and folding the resulting perpendicular triangle back down flush, with no ill-effects. Lastly, I would avoid running them on the top or bottom, whichever one you can see, as they will catch the eye and be ugly/annoying. You probably want them as close to the edge as possible so as to hide behind the slightly smaller facade opening.

Comment: If your purpose for installing these strips is to illuminate the contents of the cabinet, I'd recommend installing the light strips on the back of the face frame instead of the side of the cabinet.  If that's not your purpose, can you share what it is?

Answer (score 4):

That sort of fold will not damage non-sealed LED strips.

Ideally make the fold on a cut line so if any damage does occur it can easily be repaired by soldering in short wires.

[image]